# Why List<String> can't simultaneously be argument of a Base-class generic method and Derived-class non-generic method?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

Why `List<String>` can't simultaneously be argument of a Base-class generic method and Derived-class non-generic method?

```
 class Base {
     <T> void f(List<String> arg) {}
 }

 class Derived extends Base {
     void f(List<String> arg) {}

     // above is compile ERROR: method f(List<String>) of type Derived has the same erasure 
     //as f(List<String>) of type Base but does not override it
 }
```

I don't understand that compiler message and the reason for compilation error.

There is no problem with return type:

```
class Base {
     <T> List<String> f() { return null; }
}

class Derived extends Base {     
    List<String> f() { return null; }  // perfectly valid as return-type
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what [*type erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is?

Comment: Yes. After compilation in runtime (bytecode) there is only List everywhere (in both methods/classes). Type bounds within angle brackets are used only as safe-checks during compilation. But I don't see the problem here - why same return-types compile OK while as arguments - don't.

Comment: I don't know why that is, but I can imagine it to be related to `this`.

Comment: Note that in both cases you're defining a type parameter `T` (via `<T>`) and then simply dropping it in the overrides, but no where do you actually use the type parameter in the method (e.g. as a return-type or parameter-type). Also, dropping the type parameter only seems to cause problems when there's a parameter whose type is a parameterized type. For instance, if you use `Object` as the parameter type then both cases compile without error.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, that was a fun search.

This depends on the exact specification of when a method is said to override another method.

The relevant part is in [*§8.4.8.1 Overriding (by Instance Methods)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (I'm using the one for Java 14).

> An instance method `mC` declared in or inherited by class `C`, overrides from `C` another method `mA` declared in class `A`, iff all of the following are true:
>
> [...]
>
> - The signature of *mC* is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of *mA*.

So let's look at [*§8.4.2. Method Signature*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> Two methods or constructors, `M` and `N`, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of `N` to the the type parameters of `M`, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method `m1` is a subsignature of the signature of a method `m2` if either:
>
> `m2` has the same signature as `m1`, or
>
> the signature of `m1` is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of `m2`.
>
> Two method signatures `m1` and `m2` are override-equivalent iff either `m1` is a subsignature of `m2` or `m2` is a subsignature of `m1`.

For our case there are a couple thing to note:

1. The return value is not part of the signature, so it basically gets ignored when deciding if one method overrides another. There are additional constraints based on the return type, but these constraints do not affect if two method override each other, but if the overriding does compile. See [*§8.4.8.3 Requirements in Overriding and Hiding*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).
2. The two signatures in question are not *the same* because the don't have the same number of type parameters.
3. They are not subsignatures, because this would require one to be the erasure of the other, but both signatures contain generic types (`List<String>`). Note that this changes if there are no generics in the method signatures, i.e. if you use `List` as the parameter or if `List<String>` only appears in the return value.

=> the method in `Derived` does not override the one in `Base`.

But their erasure is the same. Erasure basically removes all type parameters. See [*§4.6 Type Erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) for the obviously way more complex details. But what matters here is that the erasure of the signatures is: `void f(List arg)`

This violates a section in [*§8.4.8.3 Requirements in Overriding and Hiding*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a type declaration T has a member method m1 and there exists a method m2 declared in T or a supertype of T such that all of the following are true:
>
> - m1 and m2 have the same name.
> - m2 is accessible (§6.6) from T.
> - The signature of m1 is not a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> - The signature of `m1` or some method `m1 overrides (directly or indirectly)has the same erasure as the signature of`m2`or some method`m2` overrides (directly or indirectly).

Of course this brings us to the question: why is the weird definition of `subsignature` used?

This is actually explained in [*§8.4.2. Method Signature*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> *The notion of subsignature is designed to express a relationship between two methods whose signatures are not identical, but in which one may override the other. Specifically, it allows a method whose signature does not use generic types to override any generified version of that method. This is important so that library designers may freely generify methods independently of clients that define subclasses or subinterfaces of the library.*

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is with your first declaration being incomplete:

```
<T> void f(List<String> arg) {}de here
```

Any generic defined before return type is normally supposed to be used in the method's argument. As it is not used; For the incompleteness, reason compiler sees the method in superclass vs child class as similar first due to the same arguments but as it sees there is a generic involved in superclass which is not involved in child class it fails to determine what it exactly means.

The return types don't play any role for this one for example, try following will still show error:

```
class Base {
     <T> List<String> f(List<String> arg) { return null; }
}

class Derived extends Base {     
    List<String> f(List<String> arg) { return null; }
}
```

I would suggest to follow the generics syntax completely in order not to have such odd behaviors.